# analysis of the opcodes used in smart contract execution on ropsten, geth

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, opcode

I've deployed the following [verified smart-contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8705c513da621a16fd1defc9de8ae7cdead01fb8#code) to ropsten:

```
contract Incrementer {
    uint iteration;

    function Incrementer() {
            iteration = 0;
    }

    function increment(uint count) {
        iteration += count;
    }

    function getIteration() constant returns (uint) {
        return iteration;
    }

}
```

What I'd like to do is call it, such that it will execute, and then I want to observe the resulting series of operations that take place in the EVM, i.e. what are the opcodes that are executed, and in what sequence. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: with https://etherscan.io/ you can watch it, they have a na api maybe this help you

Comment: Hi @Gawey - could you add some more details about how this can be done in a proper answer? Might help others wanting to know the same thing :-)

Comment: @s.matthew.english What you are looking for is debug.traceTransaction available Geth. This function takes a transaction hash and returns the step by step execution trace from the EVM.